# 2S li-ion charging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

Would it be possible to charge 2S li-ion battery with MacBook m2 charger which can output 20V 1,5A or 15V 2A or 9V 3A or 5V 3A. I am planning to use this Li-ion Lithium Battery 18650 Charging and protection Board 2S 5A board:[image]

Comment: Welcome! No, a BMS is not a battery charger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will also need a 20 V to 7.4 V charger between the 20 V AC adapter and the BMS.

Frankly, it's probably easier and cheaper to forgo the 20 V AC adapter and buy a AC-powered charger with a 7.4 V output.

Note that the BMS is not a charger. You need both a charger and a BMS. They are two different functions.

> MacBook m2 charger

That is not a charger, it's a power supply (AC adapter). The actual charger is inside the laptop.

> this Li-ion Lithium Battery 18650 Charging and protection Board

I believe that's [this one](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2S-5A-7-4V-8-4V_1600485468464.html).

That's just a BMS. It is not a charger. Their description is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you doe a quick reply. Is there any way I could charge a 2S battery with my power supply ?

Comment: "s there any way I could charge a 2S battery with my power supply ?" I already answered that question. Please re-read what I wrote.